# Ubuntu 14.04 won't work after login

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have Windows 8 installed on my computer. I followed the instructions described in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU to install Ubuntu 14.04 and use dual boot. The installation process went well and everything seemed to work until I typed in my login details and password. After that, the screen freezed completely and Ubuntu did not work. I tried to log in as a guest, but the problem persisted.

Then I tried installing Ubuntu on another computer I have (on which Windows 7 is running). Again, the installation went just fine but I faced exactly the same problem!

This is how the screen looks like http://postimg.org/image/gjf4beinv/

What could be the problem? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you re-install:  I noted in the video that the presenter recommended not downloading updates, or using the 3rd party downloads - I've found both of these to be really useful in making my systems run (read required in place of useful!).  I also generally do the 'Try Ubuntu' option first, connect to my network, and run 'Install Ubuntu' once everything is connected.

Also, I'm more of a reader than a watcher.  You might want to review some of the questions about how to install Ubuntu dual booting with windows 8, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

Comment: That didn't work.